# Include order confirmation email into PHP mail function

Tags: php, function, email, include

I need to produce an order confirmation email on PHP. I have a php file that contains the confirmation email (since it has some variables that should be printed when loaded in the main php processing the order. It looks like this:

```
**orderConf.php**
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
</head>
</body>
Dear <?php echo $firstName." ".$lastName; ?> .....
.....
</body></html>
```

Then in the main php that processes the order, I have the mail function in which I place this variable:
**orderProcessing.php**

```
$message = include ("orderConf.php");
```

Would this be the right way to do it? Or should I compose my confirmation email in a different way?

Thanks

Comment: `include() ` is not going to return that orderConf.php generated text. The text will be OUTPUT instead. you'd need to rewrite orderConf to generate a string and return that, or use output buffering to CAPTURE the output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one of few cases where [HEREDOC](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc) is all right

```
<?php
$message - <<<HERE
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
</head>
</body>
Dear $firstName $lastName
.....
</body></html>
HERE;
```

then just

```
 include ("orderConf.php");
```

and have your `$message` variable.

another option would be using [output buffering](http://php.net/manual/en/book.outcontrol.php).

Comment: how are variables used within the HEREDOC? Do I need to open/close quotes?

Answer (score 0):

This way you would just output the contents of the orderConf.php. The message should be returned by this file.

```
<?php
return <<<MSG <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
</head>
</body>
Dear <?php echo $firstName." ".$lastName; ?> .....
.....
</body></html>
MSG;
```

Or you could use the ob_ functions.

```
<?php
ob_start();
include('orderConif.php');
$message = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
```

Comment: Output buffering should be used as a last resort for patching problems. If you have to rely on output buffering then there is something wrong with your code.

Comment: @Styphon although your statement is true in general, this particular case is the very case for which OB were invented. It's not patching but straight and fair use of buffering.

Comment: Yea, after seeing so many people suggesting it I did a little googling and found out I was wrong, that it is perfect for this situation. I just came back to amend my statement above.

Comment: I actually agree with you it isn't the best solution but if there are lot's of statements in the included file this is the fastest way to make it work. I would prefer the return solution myself.

Answer (score -1):

You can't include a file into a variable like that. You would have to use file_get_contents(). However IMO that isn't the best way to do it. Instead what you should do is load your message into a variable and then use the same variable for sending an e-mail. Example below:

```
$body = '<div>Dear' . $firstName . ' ' . $lastName . '... rest of your message</div>';
```

Make sure to use inline styling in $body. Tables would probably be a good idea as well, as they work better in e-mails.

Then all you do is use:

```
$to = recepients address;
$subject = subject;
$headers = "From: " . strip_tags($_POST['req-email']) . "\r\n";
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
mail($to, $subject, '<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd"><html><body>' . $body . '</body></html>', $headers);
```